# How does IOS interpret a file opened in a browser?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, ios-extensions

Im working on a project in IOS 9.3, and im using an action extension to grab documents, images and weburls that is shared by the user.

In my info.plist I've allowed files, webpages, weburls and images as shown below.

```
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
    </dict>
```

However, when i drag a PDF file to the simulator it opens in safari, which is fine. However, if i try to share this PDF my app doesn't show up as an option.

If i use a PNG instead, that is opened through pictures, the extension is shown and works as its supposed to.

Am i wrong to assume that "NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount" includes PDF files? (Im assuming since i haven't been able to find an actual explanation of what this key covers)

And if a PDF opened in a browser is converted/interpreted as a webpage, i should be able to grab it with the "NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount"-key - right?

**UPDATE**

Didn't find the exact answer, but if someone is looking for a solution to this problem I've used a predicate to tell the extension which files it can use:

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>SUBQUERY (
                extensionItems,
                $extensionItem,
                SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments,
                $attachment,
                (
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.bmp"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.tiff"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.gif"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.tif"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.rtf"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.file-url"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.html"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.word.doc"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.excel.xls"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.encapsulated-postscript"
                )
                ).@count == 1
                ).@count == 1
            </string>
```

Which works just fine and allows me to be more specific in which files i want my extension to use.